# How can i solve this error: RuntimeError(f"applying transform {transform}") from e

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

I am building a segmentation model with PyTorch, however I have this error

```
your textRuntimeError(f"applying transform {transform}") from e
RuntimeError: applying transform <monai.transforms.spatial.dictionary.Orientationd object at 0x0000018A6EE74430>
```

This is my class where the error occurs:

```
class ShoulderNet(pytorch_lightning.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self,images, labels, weight_path):
        
        super().__init__()
        self.images = images
        self.labels = labels
        self.weight_path = weight_path
        # Basic Unet for our model
        self._model = BasicUNet(
            spatial_dims=2,
            in_channels=1,
            out_channels=2, # 2 classes : bones & background
        )
        #device = torch.device("cuda:0")
        ''' 
        We use a DiceCELoss which is a combination of a Dice Loss and Cross Entropy Loss
        '''
        
        self.loss_function = DiceCELoss(include_background=True, to_onehot_y=True, sigmoid=True) 
        self.post_pred = Compose([EnsureType('tensor', device='cpu'), AsDiscrete(argmax=True, to_onehot=2), FillHoles()]) # Standardisation of the prediction
        self.post_label = Compose([EnsureType('tensor', device='cpu'), AsDiscrete(to_onehot=2)]) # Standardisation of the labels
        self.dice_metric = DiceMetric(include_background=True, reduction='mean', get_not_nans=False) # Our metric for computing the performance of our segmentation
        
        self.best_val_dice = 0
        self.best_val_epoch = 0

    def load_weight(self):
        self._model.load_state_dict(self.weights_path)

    def forward(self, x): # Forward Loop
        return self._model(x)

    def prepare_data(self):
        data_dicts = [
            {'image': image_name, 'label': label_name} 
            for image_name, label_name in zip(self.images, self.labels) 
        ]
        train_files, val_files = data_dicts[:-20], data_dicts[20:] 
        set_determinism(seed=0)
        
        train_transforms = Compose([
            AddChanneld(keys=['image', 'label']), # we need to add a channel fo the training
            Orientationd(keys=['image', 'label'], axcodes='RAS'),
            NormalizeIntensityd(keys=['image']),

            # Applying some data augmentation
            RandGaussianNoised(keys=["image"], prob=0.5, mean=0.5, std=0.3),
            RandRotated(keys=["image", "label"], prob=0.5),
            RandGaussianSmoothd(keys=["image"], prob=0.5),
            RandFlipd(keys=["image", "label"], prob=0.5),
            RandKSpaceSpikeNoised(keys=["image"], prob=0.5),
            RandCoarseDropoutd(keys=["image"], prob=0.5, holes=50, spatial_size=20),
            RandZoomd(keys=["image", "label"], prob=0.2, min_zoom=0.8, max_zoom= 1.2),


            ToTensord(keys=["image", "label"], dtype=torch.float)
        ])

        val_transforms = Compose([
            AddChanneld(keys=["image", "label"]),
            Orientationd(keys=["image", "label"], axcodes="RAS"),
            NormalizeIntensityd(keys=['image']),
            ToTensord(keys=["image", "label"], dtype=torch.float)
        ])

        # Loading data in dataset module
        self.train_ds = CacheDataset(
            data=train_files, transform=train_transforms,
            num_workers=4, cache_rate=1.0
        )
        
        self.val_ds = CacheDataset(
            data=val_files, transform=val_transforms,
            num_workers=4, cache_rate=1.0
        )
            
    def train_dataloader(self):
        train_loader = DataLoader(
            self.train_ds, shuffle=True,
            num_workers=4, collate_fn = list_data_collate
        )
        return train_loader

    def val_dataloader(self):
        val_loader = DataLoader(
            self.val_ds, num_workers=4)
        return val_loader

    def configure_optimizers(self):
        optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(self._model.parameters(), lr=1e-3) 
        return optimizer

    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
            device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
            images, labels = batch['image'].to(device), batch['label'].to(device)
            output = self.forward(images)
            loss = self.loss_function(output, labels)
            tensorboard_logs = {'train_loss' : loss.item()}
            self.log('train_loss', loss.item())
            return {'loss':loss, 'log': tensorboard_logs}

    def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
        images, labels = batch['image'].to(device), batch['label'].to(device)
        roi_size = (512,512)
        sw_batch_size = 4
        outputs = sliding_window_inference(
            images, roi_size, sw_batch_size, self.forward)
        loss = self.loss_function(outputs, labels)
        outputs = [self.post_pred(i) for i in decollate_batch(outputs)]
        labels = [self.post_label(i) for i in decollate_batch(labels)]
        self.dice_metric(y_pred=outputs, y=labels)
        return {"val_loss": loss, "val_number": len(outputs)} 

    def validation_epoch_end(self, outputs):
        val_loss, num_items = 0, 0
        for output in outputs:
            val_loss += output['val_loss'].sum().item()
            num_items += output['val_number']
        mean_val_dice = self.dice_metric.aggregate().item()
        self.dice_metric.reset()
        mean_val_loss = torch.tensor(val_loss / num_items)
        tensorboard_logs = {
            'val_dice': mean_val_dice,
            'val_loss': mean_val_loss,
        }
        self.log('val_dice', mean_val_dice)
        self.log('val_loss', mean_val_loss)
        if mean_val_dice > self.best_val_dice:
            self.best_val_dice = mean_val_dice
            self.best_val_epoch = self.current_epoch
        print(
            f'current epoch: {self.current_epoch}'
            f"current mean dice: {mean_val_dice:.4f}"
            f"\nbest mean dice: {self.best_val_dice:.4f} "
            f"at epoch: {self.best_val_epoch}"
        )
return {"log": tensorboard_logs} # You can visualize our results on TensorBoard your text
```

The whole error is likewise :

```
python .\main_axial_segmentation.py
BasicUNet features: (32, 32, 64, 128, 256, 32).
GPU available: False, used: False
TPU available: False, using: 0 TPU cores
IPU available: False, using: 0 IPUs     
HPU available: False, using: 0 HPUs     
C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\utils\deprecate_utils.py:107: FutureWarning: <class 'monai.transforms.utility.array.AddChannel'>: Class `AddChannel` has been deprecated since version 0.8. please use MetaTensor data type and monai.transforms.EnsureChannelFirst instead.
  warn_deprecated(obj, msg, warning_category)
Loading dataset:   0%|                                                                                                                            | 0/84 [00:00<?, ?it/s] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\transforms\transform.py", line 102, in apply_transform  
    return _apply_transform(transform, data, unpack_items)
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\transforms\transform.py", line 66, in _apply_transform  
    return transform(parameters)
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\transforms\spatial\dictionary.py", line 479, in __call__
    d[key] = self.ornt_transform(d[key])
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\transforms\spatial\array.py", line 697, in __call__     
    src = nib.io_orientation(affine_)
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\utils\module.py", line 408, in __getattr__
    raise self._exception
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\transforms\transform.py", line 102, in apply_transform  
    return _apply_transform(transform, data, unpack_items)
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\transforms\transform.py", line 66, in _apply_transform  
    return transform(parameters)
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\transforms\spatial\dictionary.py", line 479, in __call__
    d[key] = self.ornt_transform(d[key])
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\transforms\spatial\array.py", line 697, in __call__     
    src = nib.io_orientation(affine_)
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\utils\module.py", line 408, in __getattr__
    raise self._exception
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\transforms\transform.py", line 102, in apply_transform  
    return _apply_transform(transform, data, unpack_items)
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\transforms\transform.py", line 66, in _apply_transform
    return transform(parameters)
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\transforms\spatial\dictionary.py", line 479, in __call__
    d[key] = self.ornt_transform(d[key])
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\transforms\spatial\array.py", line 697, in __call__
    src = nib.io_orientation(affine_)
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\utils\module.py", line 408, in __getattr__
    raise self._exception
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\transforms\transform.py", line 102, in apply_transform
    return _apply_transform(transform, data, unpack_items)
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\transforms\transform.py", line 66, in _apply_transform
    return transform(parameters)
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\transforms\spatial\dictionary.py", line 479, in __call__
    d[key] = self.ornt_transform(d[key])
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\transforms\spatial\array.py", line 697, in __call__
    src = nib.io_orientation(affine_)
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\utils\module.py", line 408, in __getattr__
    raise self._exception
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\transforms\transform.py", line 102, in apply_transform
    return _apply_transform(transform, data, unpack_items)
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\transforms\transform.py", line 66, in _apply_transform
    return transform(parameters)
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\transforms\spatial\dictionary.py", line 479, in __call__
    d[key] = self.ornt_transform(d[key])
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\transforms\spatial\array.py", line 697, in __call__
    src = nib.io_orientation(affine_)
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\utils\module.py", line 408, in __getattr__
    raise self._exception
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\transforms\transform.py", line 102, in apply_transform
    return _apply_transform(transform, data, unpack_items)
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\transforms\transform.py", line 66, in _apply_transform
    return transform(parameters)
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\transforms\spatial\dictionary.py", line 479, in __call__
    d[key] = self.ornt_transform(d[key])
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\transforms\spatial\array.py", line 697, in __call__
    src = nib.io_orientation(affine_)
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\utils\module.py", line 408, in __getattr__
    raise self._exception
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\transforms\transform.py", line 102, in apply_transform
    return _apply_transform(transform, data, unpack_items)
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\transforms\transform.py", line 66, in _apply_transform
    return transform(parameters)
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\transforms\spatial\dictionary.py", line 479, in __call__
    d[key] = self.ornt_transform(d[key])
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\transforms\spatial\array.py", line 697, in __call__
    src = nib.io_orientation(affine_)
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\utils\module.py", line 408, in __getattr__
    raise self._exception
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\transforms\transform.py", line 102, in apply_transform
    return _apply_transform(transform, data, unpack_items)
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\transforms\transform.py", line 66, in _apply_transform
    return transform(parameters)
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\transforms\spatial\dictionary.py", line 479, in __call__
    d[key] = self.ornt_transform(d[key])
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\transforms\spatial\array.py", line 697, in __call__
    src = nib.io_orientation(affine_)
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\utils\module.py", line 408, in __getattr__
    raise self._exception
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\transforms\transform.py", line 102, in apply_transform
    return _apply_transform(transform, data, unpack_items)
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\transforms\transform.py", line 66, in _apply_transform
    return transform(parameters)
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\transforms\spatial\dictionary.py", line 479, in __call__
    d[key] = self.ornt_transform(d[key])
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\transforms\spatial\array.py", line 697, in __call__
    src = nib.io_orientation(affine_)
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\utils\module.py", line 408, in __getattr__
    raise self._exception
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\transforms\transform.py", line 102, in apply_transform
    return _apply_transform(transform, data, unpack_items)
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\transforms\transform.py", line 66, in _apply_transform
    return transform(parameters)
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\transforms\spatial\dictionary.py", line 479, in __call__
    d[key] = self.ornt_transform(d[key])
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\transforms\spatial\array.py", line 697, in __call__
    src = nib.io_orientation(affine_)
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\utils\module.py", line 408, in __getattr__
    raise self._exception
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\transforms\transform.py", line 102, in apply_transform
    return _apply_transform(transform, data, unpack_items)
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\transforms\transform.py", line 66, in _apply_transform
    return transform(parameters)
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\transforms\spatial\dictionary.py", line 479, in __call__
    d[key] = self.ornt_transform(d[key])
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\transforms\spatial\array.py", line 697, in __call__
    src = nib.io_orientation(affine_)
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\utils\module.py", line 408, in __getattr__
    raise self._exception
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\transforms\transform.py", line 102, in apply_transform
    return _apply_transform(transform, data, unpack_items)
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\transforms\transform.py", line 66, in _apply_transform
    return transform(parameters)
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\transforms\spatial\dictionary.py", line 479, in __call__
    d[key] = self.ornt_transform(d[key])
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\transforms\spatial\array.py", line 697, in __call__
    src = nib.io_orientation(affine_)
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\utils\module.py", line 408, in __getattr__
    raise self._exception
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\utils\module.py", line 367, in optional_import
    pkg = __import__(module)  # top level module
monai.utils.module.OptionalImportError: import nibabel (No module named 'nibabel').

For details about installing the optional dependencies, please visit:
    https://docs.monai.io/en/latest/installation.html#installing-the-recommended-dependencies

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\Documents\fichier vs codes\bone_axial_segmentation.m\main_axial_segmentation.py", line 9, in <module>
    training_fct(images,
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\Documents\fichier vs codes\bone_axial_segmentation.m\training.py", line 39, in training_fct
    trainer.fit(net)
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\trainer\trainer.py", line 608, in fit
    call._call_and_handle_interrupt(
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\trainer\call.py", line 38, in _call_and_handle_interrupt
    return trainer_fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\trainer\trainer.py", line 650, in _fit_impl
    self._run(model, ckpt_path=self.ckpt_path)
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\trainer\trainer.py", line 1033, in _run
    self._data_connector.prepare_data()
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\trainer\connectors\data_connector.py", line 115, in prepare_data
    self.trainer._call_lightning_module_hook("prepare_data")
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\trainer\trainer.py", line 1347, in _call_lightning_module_hook
    output = fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\Documents\fichier vs codes\bone_axial_segmentation.m\model.py", line 69, in prepare_data
    self.train_ds = CacheDataset(
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\data\dataset.py", line 814, in __init__
    self.set_data(data)
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\data\dataset.py", line 841, in set_data
    self._cache = self._fill_cache(indices)
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\data\dataset.py", line 870, in _fill_cache
    return list(tqdm(p.imap(self._load_cache_item, indices), total=len(indices), desc="Loading dataset"))
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\tqdm\std.py", line 1195, in __iter__
    for obj in iterable:
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 873, in next
    raise value
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 125, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\data\dataset.py", line 884, in _load_cache_item
    item = apply_transform(_xform, item)
  File "C:\Users\Demo 1A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\monai\transforms\transform.py", line 129, in apply_transform
    raise RuntimeError(f"applying transform {transform}") from e
RuntimeError: applying transform <monai.transforms.spatial.dictionary.Orientationd object at 0x000001C1008A44F0>
```

Envirenment :
vs code
Python 3.10.9
torch '1.13.1+cpu'

I think that the problem is that I have a GPU in my machine but I dont know why it does not turn with that.

I don't know how to make it turn on GPU and how to install cuda for that

Could you please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try `pip install 'monai[all]'` to install all monai dependencies

Ref: https://docs.monai.io/en/stable/installation.html